# display textview as last item of list view

Tags: java, android

I want to display a textview as a last item of List View. Here is my xml code -

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.activity.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="8dp">

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ListView
                android:id="@android:id/list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:paddingBottom="60dp" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The list view will display card view one below other. However I want a textview as last item in the list.
For example, if i have 1 card view, I need to display textview below that.
If I have 2 card views, I need to display textview below the second card view.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Show your activity or fragment code please

Comment: listview.addfooter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265228/how-to-add-a-footer-in-listview

Comment: For this, you need to add footer view to your listview. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227182/android-adding-footer-to-listview-addfooterview

Comment: When I do , I get exception - java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inflate your view like this.

```
     LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
     context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     View root = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.yourLayout, null);
     // for footerclick
     //add code her root.setOnClickListner(...)
     listView.addFooterView(root, null, true);
```

for click try this

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, final int position, long id) {
          if(position < adapter.getCount()){ 
            Log.d("test","working");
          }
     }
 });
```

on Refresh listview

```
mListView.removeFooterView(root);
```

Comment: When I do , I get exception - java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams

Comment: Seems to work thank you :) but when i click on 2nd item in list view , its not taking click event. I need to click it second time to achieve some event.Some problem with

Comment: Thank you it works :) but the problem is when I click 2nd item or 3rd or 4th item of list view, It does not recognise. Need to click it twice.
I get java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2 for adapter.getItem()

Comment: i change the code check out the code addFotterview(root,bull,false);

Comment: Still the same problem :(

Comment: How can I make my footer view clickable?

Comment: make fotterview(root,null,true); that will make footer clickble

Comment: check out the changes

Comment: but footerview is being added multiple times as i refresh view and stil my second item of list view not clickable

Comment: when you refresh change remove the footer item cehck above code

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by adding a footer to the list view.

It is very simple, just create a layout with the required Textview. Add it as a footer to the list view as below.

```
listView.addFooterView(footerView);
```

Please find more reference to adding footer from this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265228/how-to-add-a-footer-in-listview).

Comment: When I do , I get exception - java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your ListView in LinearLayout and add TextView just below it. Then wrap that with NestedScrollView and set fillViewPort to true to still be able to scroll when TextView goes beyond screen

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.activity.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="8dp">

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fillViewport="true">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@android:id/list"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:clipToPadding="false"
                        android:paddingBottom="60dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Footer text view" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```